# beginner php mysql how to print all columns from a row

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to echo a whole row from a database if one of the columns of that row has a specified value.

Here's a simple example of what I'm trying to do: From this

[image: database]

I want to echo the whole row who have 1 as value for 'level'. So, for example, the end result would be:

> Adam Smith 1 stuff 757890
>
> Nelson Mandela 1 and another stuff 800656

So naturally I tried this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE level = '" . $askedLevel . "'";
$run_query = mysqli_query($mysql, $query);
```

But how do I go from here to echo exactly what I want?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Looks like you need to learn more about what is expected of users here. You're expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: just type your heading in the google and see what happened `php mysql how to print all columns from a row` you dont need stack overflow for this question

`

Answer (score 1):

You would loop over each row, like so:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_query)){
    echo $row["first_name"] . $row["last_name"]; 
}
```

Obviously, you would change `"first_name"` and `"last_name"` with whatever column names you require, but this is the basics of what you need to do.

`mysqli_fetch_assoc` fetches the results and puts them in an array, along with their relative column names.

As **arif_suhail_123** also pointed out, you have a security issue within your **SQL**; that is, not utilizing parameterized queries for parsing variables into your **SQL**.

To fix this, what you would do is:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysql, "SELECT * FROM data WHERE level = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'i', $askedLevel); // binding the variable $askedLevel to '?'
$result = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt); // executing the question 

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    // print rows
}
```

For reference, `i` means integer. `s` means string. `d` means double.

---

**SUGGESTION**: Now this isn't necessary for your queries to work correctly, *however*, it **will** clean up (and make more readable) your **PHP** dramatically. But, I highly suggest you switch to Object Orientated **PHP**.

It would change the above script to look something like *this*, instead:

```
$stmt = $mysql->prepare("SELECT * FROM data WHERE level = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $askedLevel);
$result = $stmt->execute();

while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
    echo $row->first_name . $row->last_name;
}
```

It's completely up to you, however! :)

Comment: please also mention this to him, that the code is not secure

Comment: @arif_suhail_123 I put the answer to the question he had first. I am currently editing my answer to also include the fact he should definitely be using parameterized queries.

Comment: yep valid answer now +1

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` wants a `mysqli_result` as its parameter, not `mysqli_stmt` - they don't interchange. So you'll need some more lines here for that paramterized query to work.. You're also not fetching the values.

Comment: @Qirel whoops! You're right! my mistake haha